# Can you sign a transaction in the front end but process it in a server backend?

Tags: transactions, signature, dapp-design

Can you sign a transaction in the front end using metamask but send the transaction to the blockchain in the backend like nodejs?

Comment: What is your use case here because the answer is yes of course, but not sure why you would like to do that ...

Comment: I have actually seen that I can just listen to the events in the backend and act on them as I wish.

Comment: Metamask doesn't allow to obtain a signed raw transaction. You could sign a message or send a transaction. They have an explanation in their repo that signing a transaction without sending it caused problems for users and a lots of customer complains.